# How to check in C++ if an application is already running before launching a new instance?

Tags: c++, windows

I have found a few references to implementation but only one clear description in C++ (Joseph Newcomers article http://www.flounder.com/nomultiples.htm#CreateMutex), but it was (c)1999 so I was a little reluctant to use it without first checking if there were "newer/better" ways today.

Thanks

Comment: C++ does not have any such mechanism. The method using a mutex as on the site you linked to is the method of choice under Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Any named object will do, can be a file, mutex, event, mailslot, TCP port, etc.  `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` tells you whether an instance already existed.

For objects in the Win32 kernel namespace, there is one change since 1999 -- because of terminal services, you now can use a prefix of `Global\` or `Local\` to specify whether it's one instance on the entire computer vs one per user logon session.

If you want something more portable, then binding a TCP port, or creating a file and exclusively locking it, tend to work well across a variety of OSes.

Comment: Actually, the issue of namespaces was discussed in the linked article

Comment: @David: It may be discussed, but the code in the article doesn't work as intended.

Comment: I'm sure you're right. The article seems absurdly over the top for what is a pretty simple problem.

Comment: One nice thing about using kernel objects like mutexes instead of files is that if the application doesn't properly clean up (as in, it crashes), the OS will deal properly with cleaning up the object. If you use a file, it may be more portable, but you (or your users) will need to deal with the nuisance of lock files that don't get cleaned up properly when the app crashes.

Comment: @Michael: You also have special files, ramdisks, etc. that aren't as persistent as a normal file.  Also, one needn't use the existence of a file, but the presence of a lock (or being open with exclusive share mode), both of which are dispelled in case of abnormal program termination.  But I agree that using a kernel object (a mailslot has some advantages, such as being able to forward arguments to the existing instance) is better for non-portable software, for that reason.

Comment: @Ben: agree.  I'm just pointing out something think about if files are being considered - I occasionally have to deal with manually deleting a file used as a lock or other signaling mechanism that's left behind after a crash. Not always a huge problem, but I consider myself somewhat tech savvy.  My Mom would probably get more frustrated. Note that if you decide to use 'special' files or ramdisks, you're probably venturing into non-portable territory anyway, so at that point you might want to still consider platform specific objects.

Comment: @Michael: True, which is why "open for exclusive access" should be preferred over "exists" when using a file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are programming on Windows, the standard way to do this is indeed to create a mutex at the start of your program. The mutex should live as long as the lifetime of your program and during this time, attempts to create a mutex with the same name will fail.

Answer (score 0):

There hasn't been any significant improvement since then. For that matter, there hasn't been any significant improvement since a [Usenet post](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32/browse_frm/thread/5e63f337cc2e7ece/14ed843a54defa34?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&q=author%3ajerry%20author%3acoffin%20CreateMutex#14ed843a54defa34) I wrote a few years before that.